# How to use select2 jQuery plugin for tokenizer?

Tags: tags, token, tokenize

I want to make an e-mail input box with an auto suggestion dropdown. I downloaded the Select2 Plugin from github & installed the .js and .css files following the plugin instruction.

I don't understand the markup for the input box and how the input box picks data to show as suggestions. Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other jquery plugin, select2 plugin also adds its feature to the jquery object. So you obtain a reference of the DOM element using `$()` and then call `select2()` on it, it converts the simple dorpdown element into a autocomplete dropdown like:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#my-dropdown").select2();
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <select id="my-dropdown">
   <option id="1">Dogs</option>
   <option id="2">Cats</option>
   <option id="3">Wolves</option>
   <option id="4">Rhinos</option>
 </select>
</body>
```

Since you need to use it for email input box. I suppose that the input box is for email ids. So what you can do is, keep the list of email ids in an array of objects. And have a `select` element with `multiple` attribute on the page.
Then on page load, just bind the array to the `select` using `select2` plugin as given below:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script>
        var list = [{id: "abcd@gmail.com", text: "Foo Bar"}, 
                    {id: "jhon.doe@abcd.com", text: "John Doe"}, 
                    {}, ....];

        $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#email-input-box").select2({data: list});
        });

      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <select id="email-input-box" multiple="multiple"></select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Once you decide on what is to be shown to the user, what a user can type like email id or the name to select etc, then you can make changes to the text field of the array.

Comment: your given code working just as HTML tag. not as per select2 plugin. after using your code same to same here just create a basic HTML drop down list.